# What will happen if i create my own String class in java?

Tags: java, classloader

When i create my own String class .If there is another class in same package , main(**String**[] args)  seems to pick my String class instead of the one present in rt.jar. My question is , why String class from rt.jar is not picked by Bootstrap Class loader in this case. My understanding is a class loading request that comes to Application loader will be delegated to bootstrap class loader.

Comment: Do NOT create your own class and call it `String`.  This is just asking for trouble, and also the furious wrath of every developer who has to maintain your code.  Call it something else, like `MyString`.  The compiler does some magic around strings and you cannot replace the builtin String class. Also it is not clear why you would want to.

Comment: I understand that its not good to call the class String. I wanted to test the delegation property of Class loader. My understanding was that the request to load the String class will be delegated to Bootstrap Loader and it will load the class from rt.jar hence the String class which i defined will not be called. But i don't understand where it is going wrong

Answer (score 8):

Because the `String` in your local package takes precedence; you can explicitly use `java.lang.String` or name your `class String` something else<sup>1</sup>.

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[] args)
```

To expand on the above, at compile time the compiler resolves class names to their fully qualified form (at the byte-code level, there aren't any `import`s). Further, Java includes a `String` *intern pool* that is initialized before your class is loaded (in order for that to function, `java.lang.String` has to be loaded before any user classes).

<sup>1<sub>Which is really a better idea, [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) classes from `java.lang` is asking for a maintenance nightmare.</sub></sup>

Comment: @DavidWallace I've edited the answer to try and more directly address the question.

Comment: OK, I've removed my downvote, since you've added the key point - that the resolution of class names happens at compile time, not at run time.  Really, that's all anyone ever needed to say, to answer this.

Answer (score 4):

> Why is the String class from rt.jar not picked by the bootstrap class loader in this case.  My understanding is a class loading request that comes to Application loader will be delegated to bootstrap class loader.

The name resolution actually happens at compile time.  The compiler decides what `String` means in the context of the source code file that is using it and then uses the full name for the resolved class (e.g. `java.lang.String` or `your.pkg.String`) in the class file.  At runtime, Java class loaders always load classes using a full class name.